# Retrieve current scale value of Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is it possible to get the current scale value of the Leaflet component?

[image: Map scale of Leaflet]

The image above shows "300 km" or "100 miles" that i would like to retrieve by a method. The existing documentation does only show how to add the scale control with specific options: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with the scale at low zoom levels (when you see a large portion of the world).

The scale that you see is actually valid for the center horizontal line of your map view. It is even slightly wrong for the corner of the map, where it is placed!

If you just want to "duplicate" that **visual** scale somewhere else, you could simply create another Scale Control and extract its HTML container instead of embedding it to your map:

```js
document.getElementById("myNewContainerId").appendChild(
    L.control.scale(options).onAdd(map)
);
```

If you want to read the actual pixel length and text of the Scale Control, you could retrieve them through the internal `_mScale.style.width` and `_mScale.innerHTML` properties of the Scale Control. Replace `_mScale` by `_iScale` if you want the imperial values instead of the metric ones.

Otherwise, if you want to be able to measure some distance between 2 points on the map, you should rather use the [`myLatLng.distanceTo(otherLatLng)` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng-distanceto), which would be far more accurate, as it would not only use the correct scale at the `myLatLng` actual latitude, but also correct for the possible different scale along the path to `otherLatLng` if it is placed at a different latitude.

> Returns the distance (in meters) to the given LatLng calculated using the Haversine formula. See [description on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Comment: So true! We have to consider the geographic (spherical) coordinate system. Thanks for the informaion.