# Leaflet - put controls outside the div map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I made the following app :
http://lae2.alwaysdata.net/carte/exppng/

I'd like to put my two controls (leaflet-control-zoom and leaflet-control-layers) outside the div map. I'd want to use them inside the grey area for example.

I'd like to know if it's possible  : I looked for some tricks but I didn't find anything...

If it is could you help me ?

Thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be interested in the following posts:

- [Retrieve current scale value of Leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35889088/retrieve-current-scale-value-of-leaflet/35891206#35891206)
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83942/display-a-control-zoom-bar-outside-map-container-in-leaflet

In essence:

```js
document.getElementById("myNewContainerId").appendChild(
    L.control.layers(base, overlays).onAdd(map)
);
```

External sources:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/leaflet-js/control$20onadd/leaflet-js/rKMZX3PKFuI