# Placing a Leaflet legend outside of the map div

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I just finished working on the legend for my map, but now i want to place the legend **outside of the leaflet map**.

I got two div's in my index.html: one with ID "map" and one with ID "legend".

```
var legend = new L.control({position: 'topright'});

legend.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
    categories = ['MacDonalds', 'Subway', 'KFC', 'BurgerKing', 'Dominos', 'NYPizza', 'Kwalitaria', 'overig'];

    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML += '<i style="background:' + getColor(categories[i]) + '"></i> ' + (categories[i] ? categories[i] + '<br>' : '+');
    }

    return div;
};

$.when($.ajax(initialize())).then(function () {

    legend.addTo(map);

});
```

Is it possible to change the location of the legend from the 'map' div to another div and if so, how?

Comment: When you do `legend.addTo(map)`, what happens if you change the `map` to your other div?

Comment: I tried that already, but the only thing that happens is that the legend disappears. If i run Firebug i get the following error message: TypeError: map._controlCorners is undefined

Comment: Hmm. It might be that your `map` variable is undefined. Can you put your code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I haven't used jsfiddle before, so i hope you can work with it. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/rkwv54dc/2/). `Map` was indeed undefined, i didn't see the legend before. I fixed this by using the last 3 lines of code.

Comment: Unfortunately since I don't have your data, [it isn't loading properly in the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rkwv54dc/4/). Instead of initializing the legend so far down, try moving that up into the `initialize()` function right after the map has been created.

Comment: Yeah figured as much, I work with a local database for my data. Moving the legend up into `initialize()` fixed an error i had before. Don't need the last couple of lines anymore, thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041651/leaflet-put-controls-outside-the-div-map