# Put Leaflet controls outside of map div in Shiny environment

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, leaflet

Is it possible to move Leaflet controls outside of the map div in a Shiny environment?

Example: 
[image]

From the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

shinyApp(

  ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel("This is where I want to put the leaflet layers control", width = 3), 
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("map", width = "100%"), 
      width = 9)
  ), 

  server <- function(session, input, output){

    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>% 
        addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldTerrain", group = "Layer1") %>% 
        addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "Layer2") %>% 
        addLayersControl(position = "topleft", 
                         baseGroups = c("Layer1", "Layer2"), 
                         options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = F))
    })  # END RENDERLEAFET
  }  # END SERVER
)  # END SHINYAPP
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041651/leaflet-put-controls-outside-the-div-map), but it was specific to leaflet.js, which differs significantly from Shiny. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: both the layer and the zoom controls or only layer?

Comment: does the answer work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is (partly?) possible with JS.

**Using JS within Shiny**

To use JS within shiny `library(shinyjs)` is a nice shortcut. Use `useShinyjs()` on the ui side and `runjs()` on the server side.

**Modify HTML**

As you want to modify the DOM, you have to know that one has to wait until the DOM is completely build, before you can modify it. Use `session$onFlushed(function() {}` to ensure you start modifying only when the DOM is completely build.

**Repositioning the HTML elements**

First, you will have to know how the elements, you want to reposition and the target where you want to insert it, are named. In order to do so run the app (in a browser) right click on the required element and choose "inspect". 
Next, the procedure would be to save the "element-to-reposition" in a variable, remove it from the leafletmap and add it outside the map.

The JS code could look like this:

```
     var targetName = "div.leaflet-control-layers.leaflet-control-layers-expanded.leaflet-control"
     var target = document.querySelector(targetName);
     var dest = document.querySelector("div.col-sm-3");
     document.querySelector(targetName).remove()
     dest.appendChild(target)
```

**Challenge**
If you put that all together you will notice, the control is not within the grey box, but below it. Given the code above, the reason is that it was appended to `div.col-sm-3` and not to `form.well` (because it does not work for `form.well`). I had the idea to add an empty container in the UI `tags$div(id = "insertContainer", "")` and insert it in there, but that doesn´t work either. I dont know how important it is for you to get in within the grey box, would look better probably. Maybe someone could help out there.

**Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(shinyjs)

  ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    sidebarPanel(HTML("This is where I want to put the leaflet layers control"), width = 3, height = 5), 
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("map", width = "100%"), 
      width = 9)
  )

  server <- function(session, input, output){

    session$onFlushed(function() {
      runjs('
             var targetName = "div.leaflet-control-layers.leaflet-control-layers-expanded.leaflet-control"
             var target = document.querySelector(targetName);
             var dest = document.querySelector("div.col-sm-3");
             document.querySelector(targetName).remove()
             dest.appendChild(target)
      ')
    })

    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>% 
        addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldTerrain", group = "Layer1") %>% 
        addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "Layer2") %>% 
        addLayersControl(position = "topleft", 
                         baseGroups = c("Layer1", "Layer2"), 
                         options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = F))
    })  # END RENDERLEAFET
  }  # END SERVER


runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Comment: This does work for the example given, but unfortunately does not for my actual app because there are multiple leaflet panes AND well panels, which I think confuses the js code! So neitherthe targetName nor dest are unique.

Comment: Accepted because it does technically achieve what was asked, but can only be applied if you have a single leaflet pane and well panel.