# Move Leaflet plugin to different div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, leaflet

I can group my layers with the xxx plugin. I want to place this layer I want to make on the divs that I have created, how can I do this.

```
    <div id="divProjectError" class="errorMsg col-xs-12">
                <h1 class="text-center" id="abc"><ins>LAYERS</ins></h1>           
   </div>
   <div id="mapdiv" class="col-md-9"></div>
```

Example:

[image]

```
var baseLayers = {
        "ddd": mywms,       

    };
    L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35889088/retrieve-current-scale-value-of-leaflet/35891206#35891206